# How to get random value from defined array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create Rock-Scissors-Paper game using ts. I defined userChoice variable with type UserChoice

```
type UserChoice = "" | "Scissors" | "Paper" | "Rock"
```

I have a mode to play with the bot. For creating random value I create function getRandomItem which should return "Scissors" | "Paper" | "Rock".
When the user chose nothing it must return not the same(always) random element as the bot's one

```
 const getRandomItem = (userEmpty: boolean = false ) : UserChoice => {
  let index = !userEmpty ? Math.round(Math.random() + Math.random()) : Math.round(Math.random() * 2)
  let value: UserChoice = ['Scissors', 'Paper', 'Rock'][index]
  return value
}
```

Explain why ts says that value is not appropriate and give the right solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To TypeScript, the array in values is `Array<string>` I am a little surprised, and not, that it doesn't understand what's going on. Anyways I would add

```
const possibleValues: Array<UserChoice> = ['Scissors', 'Paper', 'Rock']
const value: UserChoice = possibleValues[index]
```

Something about this seems a bit wrong considering according to the type, it is possible to get "", even though it can't be... But the fix works. Perhaps refactor to have two different types if you truly care about this?

Comment: My major issue with doing it this way is one could do ['Rock', 'Rock', 'Rock', 'Rock', etc] and TS it would be fine

Comment: I decided to remove "" value from UserChoice type and create UserAfk variable for that purpose. But it seems that I just had to define that array with type UserChoice[] as you did.